# Steiner Tree and minimum spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-algorithms, optimization, randomized-algorithms, tree

If I must connect: $$2^k$$ terminals in a Steiner Tree choosen randomly and connect them with the cheapest component; "loss - contracting algorithm" is a good way? Or is an "Iterative Randomized Rounding" more appropriate? At the end the cost of minimum spanning tree should be: $$c(T)<=1+(1/k)$$

Thanks

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a good question. (At least, once it's corrected by multiplying the rhs of the equation by the cost of the Steiner tree.)

Comment: Are you talking about directed component cut relaxation?